# why sudo gem install fails but gem install succeeds?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, sudo, gem

I simply do

```
sudo gem install sqlite3
```

and have response:

**sudo: gem: command not found**

```
Then I do gem install sqlite3
```

and it works. Where is the problem with sudo ?

Comment: Because you have to use `sudo` to run those commands which are located in `/sbin` It might be possible that `gem` command is not located in `/sbin` directory.. Run this command to know the entries of `gem`: `sudo dpkg -L gem`

Comment: If it helps you somewhat then I would like to post it as an answer so that it would help others also, to solve such issues.. and also Comments can be easily deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have to use `sudo` to run those commands which are located in `/sbin`. It might be possible that gem command is not located in `/sbin` directory.. Run this command to know the entries of `gem`:

```
    sudo dpkg -L gem
```